# What's the difference between Admob and Adwhirl?

Tags: android, iphone

I'm trying to figure what the difference is and which one would be more profitable for my app?

Answer (score 6):

Admob and Adwhirl were originally two completely different frameworks. Admob bought adwhirl so both frameworks are now owned by Admob company.

Adwhirl doesn't have its own ads, it takes them from other advertising channels. Admob has its own ads.

If you use Admob, you get only the ads from Admob.
If you use Adwhirl, you have to register separately for every advertising channel you want to use and is supported by Adwhirl (Admob, Millenium Media etc.), download its libraries, add it to your project and setup it.
Then you can setup the percentage for every advertising channel (some channels can be preferred over other channels), setup your house ads etc.

On Android I found Admob framework to be more stable than Adwhirl framework (I had problems with differrent banner sizes from different channels).

Note that nobody will say which framework will be the most profitable. More channels don't mean more profit!

Comment: I want to fetch ads from my own server. How can i do that? is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Admob is a advertisement SDK that allows you to show advertisements just from google or Admob.

Adwhirl allows you to user MULTIPLE advertisement SDKs. like Admob, And others all together and set  the percentage of which one you want to show the most.

So i think that Adwhirl will be more profitable.

Comment: This is only true if you have more then one adprovider activated. If you want to use only admob adwhirl will generate unused requests and reduce the CTR rate of your app. This may cause admob to downrate your app and display low profit ads only.